# Retaining multiple selectbox values in struts2

Tags: struts2

Hi i have a problem with the multiple select box of struts2.

```
<s:select name="test" id="test" multiple="true" size="2" list="testlist" theme="simple" listKey="testkey" listValue="testvalue" />
```

The select box name "test" is a field name in my entity.The list data is displaying and i can select multiple items and its stored in the database.But the problem is i could not retain the selected values while modification.But i have noticed that i can retain the value if i select only one item.Any idea?.

Comment: What do you mean by retaining? Do you want to preselect the values stored in the database?

Comment: i just want to display the stored values as selected items in the select box while modification

Comment: You can do it using the `value` attribute as explained in the answer posted by @jaiwo99. If you want more control you can use javascript/jquery to do that

Answer (score 0):

you have to define attribute "value", check the example:

```
<s:select label="Pets"
       name="petIds"
       list="petDao.pets"
       listKey="id"
       listValue="name"
       multiple="true"
       size="3"
       required="true"
       value="%{petDao.pets.{id}}"
/>
```